# Observable<String> Not Valid Return Type in Kotlin

Tags: android, types, kotlin, observable, event-bus

I'm trying to learn Kotlin in Android. What I'm finding out very quickly is that I am having trouble passing variables around from `Activity->TabsAdapter->Fragments` and back again. One of the things that would really help would be a *simple* event bus, but I've found that I can't get those to work. The problem is that one of the common return types `Observable<String>` that is continually referred to in all the docs I've seen is not recognized by Kotlin.

Take this example (from this site: https://josiassena.com/eventbus-with-rxjava2-using-kotlin/):

[image]

The site says that the example should work with Kotlin, but this does not. (Many sites seem to have similar, I'm just using this as an example, not to pick on them in particular).

I've seen other event bus systems using things like dagger 2, but this doesn't help me at all because I need *simple* so that I can see how one library is working at a time without misunderstanding what library is doing what. Does someone have a simple event bus in Kotlin that will actually work?

Comment: `Observable` is from RxJava, isn't it? Add that dependency.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. The docs for that site are bad.

Comment: FYI, you can achieve singleton pattern in kotlin with `object` keyword, no need to have enum with single instance.

Comment: post your code directly and not an image of it

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependencies to your app/build.gradle:

```
// RxJava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'    
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0'
```